# Java обертка для AtomicReference, с которой работают несколько сервисов

Tags: java, atomic

Есть такое синхронизированное хранилище в приложении на джаве:

```
private AtomicReference<HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>> data;
```

С ним работает несколько сервисов в разных потоках. С хранилищем выполняются операции чтения, добавления и изменения. Во что можно завернуть `data`, чтобы было удобно работать с ним из разных сервисов? Интересует именно архитектурный подход.

Comment: Разрешите уточнить, почему нельзя использовать просто ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> ?

Comment: @DaysLikeThis, хорошо, можно и так. Все равно не знаю, как предоставить эту мапу одновременно нескольким сервисам.

Comment: если спринг, то класс помечается как service или component, затем инжектится туда, где он нужен. Если не спринг, класс делается синглтоном и доставляется в необходимые классы через конструкторы, либо с помощью вспомогательного класса <name>Helper получаем контекст в месте использования